# Snowflake DB: How to run a report showing all database/schema names?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

In Snowflake database, I can have a report showing all database names by

```
SELECT * from information_schema.databases;
```

In each DB, I can select all schema names by

```
select catalog_name as database,
       schema_name
from   snowflake.information_schema.schemata
order  by database, schema_name asc;
```

I want a report to show everyone databases and their schema.  How can I do that?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ACCOUNT_USAGE views](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html) to generate a report containing all DBs with their respective schemas in an account.

```
select db.database_Name, sch.schema_name  
from SNOWFLAKE.account_usage.databases db 
inner join SNOWFLAKE.account_usage.schemata sch 
   ON  db.database_name = sch.catalog_name 
group by 1,2 order by 1;
```

Note: Only schmeas which have access granted to current role will be visible. For the whole list of DBs and schemas use ACCOUNTADMIN role.

Comment: Note that information in the SNOWFLAKE database is 45 minutes to 3 hours behind the changes. So if you create or drop databases or schemas, it may not be captured right away in this SQL.

Comment: select db.database_Name, 
       sch.schema_name  
from   SNOWFLAKE.account_usage.databases db 
join   SNOWFLAKE.account_usage.schemata  sch 
  ON   db.database_name = sch.catalog_name 
order by 1 desc;                                                                  
---- I removed group by, no need for it

Comment: I would have added a where clause like this WHERE Sch.DELETED IS NULL and db.DELETED IS NULL instead of a group by.

Answer (score 2):

To get all schemas in an account, you can do this (note that it only reports on what the current role has privileges on):

```
show schemas in account;
```

If you want to filter the results, you can use the result_scan immediately after running the show, which is a metadata query. It may look something like this:

```
select "database_name" as DATABASE_NAME
"name" as SCHEMA_NAME
from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
where SCHEMA_NAME not in ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA') -- optional filter(s)
;
```